# How to autofill password in shell script?

Tags: shell

Please tell me what is wrong in this, the password is not getting auto-filled:

```
for host in host001 host002 host003 host004 host005 host006 host101 host102
do
  echo "$host"
  ssh $host expect "*assword: " send -- "PASSWORD\r" interact zgrep -a "127112456" /opt/log/archive/*files*2022*04*03*
done
```

Comment: Thanks Biffen, but it's still not working.. It's still asking me to enter the password instead of auto-filling

Comment: I merely formatted your code to make it readable. But why are you running `expect` on the remote host?! Why are you using `expect` at all instead of SSH keys, or at least `sshpass`?